# setting the size of array

Tags: c, arrays

i am solving a problem. In my code i have two arrays
array[];
array2[];

i am inputing 2 numbers through scanf , and i want the size of arrays to be the count of number 1 and 2 e.g

```
int x;
int y;
scanf(" %d %d\n",&x,&y);
int indexX[x*y];
int indexY[x*y];
```

This does not work.
Being new to C im quite lost how to implement it , is the only way dynamicly allocate memory? If no , how can i achieve wanted result ? Or how could i dynamicly alocate the memory for it?
my code throws error

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘indexX’ [-Wvla]
warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘indexY’ [-Wvla]
```

Comment: How are you compiling this code?

Comment: This code is OK. Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain how the behaviour differs from what you expected.

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: The `\n` on the end of the scanf format string is probably a mistake (if running your program interactively, it will mean that execution doesn't proceed until you've entered two numbers and also some more text)

Comment: Indeed, you needn't worry about newlines when scanning integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error messages, you compile with a C++ compiler. Do not! C is not C++ and C++ is not C with classes. They are different languages. As the messages state, C++ does not provide VLAs (see below).

Use a standard-compliant C compiler, or at least a C99 compiler. *Variable length arrays* (VLAs) were added with the C99 release of the standard as a mandatory feature. C11 relaxed this by making it optional, but most (if not all) compilers which support C99 also implement it in C11 mode.

before defining the array, you should verify `scanf` really set these two variables by checking the result of `scanf`. Otherwise you use uninitialised variables, which is undefined behaviour and may (likely - will) result in strange behaviour - at best.
Additinally you can also initialise the variables before `scanf` to `1` (a VLA of size 0 is also undefined behaviour). This way you can check later and are still safe with the VLA definition.

**Warning:** Most, if not all modern implementations place VLAs on the stack. The size of the stack is normally limited to some 100 bytes (embedded systems) up to some MiB (standard OS like Windows, OS-X, Linux). There is no check if the VLA fits onto the stack, so you should not allocate too large arrays. If you are not sure, better use dynamically allocated memory (`malloc`& friends).

Comment: Re. C11, it's worth noting that really implementations just have the option of *not* supporting VLAs, and if they don't they have to say so (by defining `__STDC_NO_VLA__`). This puts it in the same category as threads, complex numbers, or IEEE floating-point support: on mainstream desktop platforms, you should really expect it to be supported unless told otherwise.

Comment: @Leushenko: I already mentioned that: "... C11 relaxed this by making it optional". IMO this was a bad decission, because VLAs can be really helpful.